# Dit-on « À quelle université étudiez-vous » ou « Dans quelle université étudiez-vous? »?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Dit-on plutôt: « À quelle université étudiez-vous ? » ou « Dans quelle université étudiez-vous »?

Comment: Nous allons vous présenter dans cet article les 16 étapes à suivre pour **faire ses études *dans* une université publique en France** Il me semble que *faire des études convient mieux*. https://etudier-en-france.net/faire-ses-etudes-dans-une-universite-publique-en-france/

Comment: Ça s’énonce bien, effectivement.

Comment: Mais dans la mesure du possible je préfère me passer des verbes dits « passe-partout », et malheureusement le verbe « faire » a la mauvaise réputation d’en être un et de figurer en tête de liste.

Comment: Certaines fois comme par exemple: construire un maison au lieu de faire une maison....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dans une interrogative, on rencontre les deux.

Dans une affirmative, ***à*** est au contraire quasiment la seule préposition rencontrée.

[image]

Les phrases proposées sont soutenues. Dans une conversation courante en France, on entendra plutôt :

> Tu fais tes études dans quelle fac ?
> Tu vas à/dans quelle fac ?
> Tu es/vas dans quelle école ? (ingénieurs, informatique, commerce, etc.)
> Tu fais tes études où ? (ne présume pas du type d'établissement)

Comment: Bien vu pour la différence interrogative/affirmative. Pour une phrase proche "Tu es dans quelle école (de commerce/ d'ingénieur) ?" semble convenir parfaitement en revanche.

Comment: @XouDo Oui, c'est vrai. Université est réducteur en France où beaucoup d'études supérieures se font dans des (grandes) écoles ou autres, hors du cadre des universités.